# Remove <span> from Html.ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, materialize

I am trying to use the data-error attribute in Materialize.css to handle all error messaging for a form using ASP.NET Core.  I have a model class using attributes for server side validation.   I would like to populate several HTML attributes with the validation settings within the Model to avoid having duplicate code.

For example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
data-error=@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

However, the `<span>` tags that are generated by ASP.NET cause issues.  Is there a way to just get the raw text without the markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class with extension method to extract text between span tags like below:

```
public static class DeleteSpan //Name of class could be any you want
{
    public static HtmlString ValidationTextNoTags<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var result = "";
        Regex regex = new Regex("<span.*?>(.*?)<\\/span>");//regular expression to extract text between span tags

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            result = writer.ToString();
        }
        //get the actual content between tags
       result = regex.Match(result).Groups[1].ToString();

       return new HtmlString(result);
    }
}
```

And then use in the View like that:

```
     @Html.ValidationTextNoTags(m => m.FirstName)
```

or

```
        <div class="col-md-4" data-error="@Html.ValidationTextNoTags(m =>m.FirstName)">
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**:  Since we are always dealt with single `span` tag we can use just `Substring` instead of Regex:

```
public static class DeleteSpan
{
    public static HtmlString ValidationTextNoTags<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var result = "";

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            result = writer.ToString();
        }
        //get the actual content between tags
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1, result.IndexOf("</span>") - result.IndexOf(">") - 1);

        return new HtmlString(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Regex for HTML? Really?

Comment: @Julian Think in this cast it is acceptable. Parse whole HTML document is madness, I agree, but here is just 1 tag which almost always has the same classes. Or is there something I am missed?